# How to execute a code for within a loop python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to repeat same code for n times ,but without error the below 'for loop' is excuting for only one time
Need to run from reading input file to saving the output file for n times with in loop
Here is the python code that i am trying to run

```
for i in range(4):
     input_1   = pd.read_csv('D:/input_1.txt',sep='\t')
     input_pivot =  input_1.pivot_table (index = ['Year','Month'] ,columns=['Gender'], 
                                        aggfunc={
                                                 'Tatal_sales':'sum',
                                                 'Tatal_sprofit':'mean' })                                              
                                                 
     input_pivot.to_csv('D:/Output.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Just need to run above same code for 4 times
Any modifications required?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is executed 4 times, however you never change the input and output files. Also, don't use `input` as name, it's a built-in function.

Comment: This loop run 4 times but you keep overwriting the same file

Answer (score 0):

You repeat the same piece of code 4 times, since you do not use the changing variable `i`.

If you would run the following code, you will get 4 different files:

1. Output0.txt
2. Output1.txt
3. Output2.txt
4. Output3.txt

```
    for i in range(4):
         input_1   = pd.read_csv('D:/input_1.txt',sep='\t')
         input_pivot =  input_1.pivot_table(
             index = ['Year','Month'],
             columns=['Gender'], 
             aggfunc={
                 'Total_sales':'sum',
                 'Total_profit':'mean'
             }
         )                                              
                                                     
         input_pivot.to_csv(f'D:/Output{i}.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```